# Why can I cast pointers of unrelated classes without error?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I've been experimenting with pointers and written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

struct A
{
    int a;
    char b;
    A(){ a = 4; }
};

struct B
{
    int c;
    B(){ c = 5; }
};

A *a = new A;
B *b = new B;

int main()
{ 
    a = (A*)b; 
    cout << a -> a; //5
}
```

Why `B*` can be converted to `A*`? Can any pointer be converted to any other pointer?

Comment: Even if your compiler says nothing (because an explicit cast means "i´m aware of potential problems, don´t warn me"), it´s just plain wrong what you´re doing. That it gives the expected result is coincidence (because a and c have the same byte offsets and type in A and B)

Comment: It is not quite true that a pointer of any type can be converted to any other type. But it can be converted to far more types than it should be.

Comment: @Beta Can you provide suitable example?

Comment: The language allows you to cast a pointer to anything to a pointer to (mostly) anything else. The result just can't be safely used except in a few limited cases.

Comment: in c, you could cast types from void * to say char * quite safely iirc.

Comment: c-style cast `(A*)` is a sledge hammer. Use a `static_cast<A*>` to let the compiler check if your types are related. @mark-b Maybe that was closed as dupe too quickly :-/ ...

Comment: An example of what? A safe conversion, an unsafe conversion, or a conversion forbidden by the language?

Comment: @DTSCode If the original pointer you stored in void * was in fact char *. Same in C++

Comment: i was talking about casting pointers. im aware. and it doesnt have to just be char *

Comment: @_St_Antario Doesn't my answer solve your question. Is there something missing, you still don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

> "Can any pointer be converted to any other pointer?"

If you use a c-style cast like this, yes.

```
a = (A*)b;
```

The structure pointed to by `b` will be just (re-)interpreted, just as it would be an `A`. The correct c++ equivalent is

```
a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(b);
```

What you'll experience from such casts by means of consistency is unlikely to fit what's expected.
In other words: You'll experience all kinds of *undefined behavior*, accessing any members of `a` after doing such cast.

---

You **should** use a `static_cast<>` to let the compiler check, if those types are related, and can be casted *somehow* reasonably

```
a = static_cast<A*>(b);
```

Check these online samples to see the differences of [`static_cast<>`](http://ideone.com/2XWqUK) and [`reinterpret_cast<>`](http://ideone.com/8wpavh).